# Why I have same value at search function?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a problem.So, I have a Form with 2 select options:

```
<label class="select">
    {{ Form::select('timeframe', [
    '' => 'Select',
    '1' => 'Current',
    '0' => 'Past'],null,['id' => 'contact_timeframe']) }}
    <i></i>
</label>
```

I just made it with value 1 by default, and with a javascript function, the values changes on click.The problem is, by default, if I press search on my search field, it searching for `timeframe = 1` (current), but if I press toggle button to past, the value of button is 0, but at search doesn't work, my `&timeframe=` from search bar just dissapear.If I press reset button, all fields are empty, but the `timeframe` field is set on `value=0`. What's logical here? I just want to make my time field, from search, works. I need `value = 1` for current, and `value = 2` for past.

**Toggle**

```
<label class="switchS" >
                            <input onclick="change()" type="checkbox" name="timeframe" value="1" id="contact_timeframe"
 checked="checked">
<span class="sliderS round" style="border-radius: 0px;top: -20px;width: 200px;height: 33px;border-width: 1px;border-color:  #bbb;position: relative;margin-left: -75px" ></span>
                                </label>
```

**JavaScript function**

```
<script>
 function change() // no ';' here
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("contact_timeframe");
    if (elem.value === "1") {
    elem.value = "0";
   } else if (elem.value === "0") {
    elem.value = "1";
   }

    }
  </script>
```

Comment: your sentence seems a little bit confusing

Comment: can u simplify it for me

Comment: I have a select option which i want to convert it to a toggle button with value 1 for current, and 0 for past.This is for my search field.On current position, it works, but when I press for Past, I receive `null` at `dd($timeframe);`

Comment: okay. how does the search work in your controller. or are you using javascript for the search?

Comment: this is for my fields from search page : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgKqEW